# Problems with R reshape idvar

Tags: r, reshape

I'm trying to use `reshape` to convert from long to wide, and my `timevar` doesn't seem to be recognized appropriately.  The time variable is Year; there are three `idvars`; and there is one variable (n) that I want under each Year once it's converted to wide format.  However, Year is put into a single column with the col.name `n.c("2005","2006","2007")`.  I've converted Year to `numeric`, `integer`, and `character`, and get a different version of wrong each time.  My code is as follows:

```
wide_df <- reshape(df, timevar="Year", 
           idvar = c("Race","Category","Outcome"),
           direction = "wide")
```

Is there a formatting issue that I'm unaware of?  Or could it be problematic that I've used `group_by` for some of the `idvars` in the data.frame from which df was derived?

Comment: Can you provide your `df`, or small data representative of it at least? It's a bit hard to debug without having the data.

Comment: You can use `dput()` for that matter. Read following link to learn [How to provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).